# nvm reinstall-packages-from does not reinstall packages

Tags: node.js, nvm

I don't know how to do to get nvm auto reinstall all global packages. As you can see in the picture.

I already have Express and a lot other packages in 4.4.3, and want to move to 4.4.4, tried to follow the instruction, Gooogle but don't know why.

[image: can not reinstall packages]

When I use `cd` command to look at 4.4.4 folder, nothing there:
[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on nvm github, and got this answer:

> it looks like your npm is broken on v4.4.3 - there's not really any way to fix that :-/

So, I have to do it manually.